# Add annotation text to boxTick

Tags: d3.js

I would very much appreciate support on Mike Bostocks' [Box Plots](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061502)
Until now, I have been unable to figure how to add specific text annotations - for example with .append("text") - adjacent to each of the `boxTick` and `whiskerTick` for example to describe to the viewer what these values are, like "Q3" or whatever.

*What would be a good way to achieve this?*

Comment: You gotta change the box.js by appending a text similar to the way the **boxTicks** are done and change the **dx** attribute accordingly. That simple. If you do not get that, please add a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/) and I'll help you out.

Comment: Thank you Shashank, I would appreciate that assistance very much.
Here is the jsfiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/r47j9xzf/10/](https://jsfiddle.net/r47j9xzf/10/)
I could not find a way to read the csv, amd so I left the csv in the `pre` tags.

Comment: After a long session over at [https://gitter.im/d3/d3](https://gitter.im/d3/d3), the solution is still not there.
If anyone can find a solution, then that would be great.
Just to clarify, the issue::
The **Box** has _3_ numbers marking its ticks and and the **Whiskers** have _two_ numbers.
Now if the number of say the upper edge of the box is  **99**, then I need it to say **Q3: 99** (or something) and if the Median Line is **27**. the it should say **Median: 27** (or whatever).

Comment: Hey I'm so sorry I couldn't get it done yesterday. I'll get it done by EOD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working demo:

[Plunkr with description for box and whisker ticks in a box plot](http://plnkr.co/edit/7jQciWewjFRRSkd4Nj98?p=preview)

I'm just using the same logic (using index `i`) used to  determine the position of the tick i.e. `dx`

Relevant code changes:

**For box ticks:**

```
.text(function(d, i) {
    var quartile = i & 1 ? 'Median' : !i ? 'Q1' : 'Q3';
    return quartile + ': ' + format(d);
})
```

**For whisker texts:**

```
.text(function(d, i) {
   return (!i ? 'LW: ' : 'UW: ') + format(d);
})
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Hope this helps.

Comment: _Very elegant indeed_. Thank you so much Shashank :-)

Comment: Glad I could help. If you think this is the right answer, please mark it as the correct one. Thanks.

Comment: Oops - there - _its the perfect answer_